# Failing to integrate javascript code into my html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add JS code to my HTML document. I am simply testing the functionality, so I am trying to create and display some text when an event occurs.

I seem to be missing some key component. Can anyone see what I am missing or if my html/js is causing the problem?

[image: HTML fragment]

[image: Javascript function]

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 mistakes.

1. In javascript, you defined it `refresh()` but called `refesh()` in the HTML.
2. In the `refresh()` function, you define `div1` element but in the last line you append not exist element `div`

Comment: Ah didn't see this one. Good eye (:

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you have linked your javascript just fine.

However, your function, refresh(), was spelt wrong in your HTML,

You wrote `refesh()` in the HTML, and in your javascript, you called it `refresh()`.

Totally understand, these problems are killer in the early days!

Cheers